# What language are Visual Studio solution (.sln) files written in?

Tags: visual-studio, languages, projects-and-solutions

I suppose that maybe what made me ask this question is, that every time I do a commit in Git the .sln  files comes up whenever there were changes. So, as a person who reviews all my changes when I do a commit I tend to look at the solution file as well (just observing what projects may have been added, or maybe configuration changes). I think that after a while I just got curious. Also, I guess I started thinking about how portable one of these solutions might be (if it was written in a practical language like the *.csproj* or *.vbproj* files).

I suppose that this won't affect me in any sort of way, like I said I am just curious. So, what language (if any) are Visual Studio solutions written in? Here is an off-hand example of what the inside of a solution looks-like (taken from MSDN):

```
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "Project1", "Project1.vbproj", "{8CDD8387-B905-44A8-B5D5-07BB50E05BEA}"
EndProject
Global
  GlobalSection(SolutionNotes) = postSolution
  EndGlobalSection
  GlobalSection(SolutionConfiguration) = preSolution
       ConfigName.0 = Debug
       ConfigName.1 = Release
  EndGlobalSection
  GlobalSection(ProjectDependencies) = postSolution
  EndGlobalSection
  GlobalSection(ProjectConfiguration) = postSolution
   {8CDD8387-B905-44A8-B5D5-07BB50E05BEA}.Debug.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
   {8CDD8387-B905-44A8-B5D5-07BB50E05BEA}.Debug.Build.0 = Debug|x86
   {8CDD8387-B905-44A8-B5D5-07BB50E05BEA}.Release.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
   {8CDD8387-B905-44A8-B5D5-07BB50E05BEA}.Release.Build.0 = Release|x86
  EndGlobalSection
  GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
  EndGlobalSection
  GlobalSection(ExtensibilityAddIns) = postSolution
  EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

I've read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx) and also the Visual Studio [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) where solutions are discussed, but can find no mention of what syntax or language it is that the solutions are represented as.

Comment: They're written in Visual Studio Solution File Language.  No, really.  It says right at the top of one of my solution files: "Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok, so because they say Format Version 12.00 you think that means they are talking about the *language* used in the file?

Comment: If you're referring to a *programming language,* I'm pretty sure that's not Turing Complete.  This is a configuration file; vendors are free to write their configuration files in whatever format they want to.  Nothing obligates them to any sort of standard.  If you're wondering why it's not in something standard like XML, it's probably for historical reasons.  Note that they *do* use XML for CSPROJ files.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah I did notice that they were using XML in the .csproj files, which *also* made me wonder about what the solution files were written in. Thanks.

Comment: Nowadays XML would be a better choice, if for no other reason that with a bit of reflection and about a dozen lines of code it translates directly into C# objects.  But if it ain't broke...

Comment: The format version simply relates to the version of Visual Studio. An incomplete list can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32753067/1371040)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656016/why-doesnt-sln-files-use-xml-format-in-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264589/visual-studio-what-is-the-format-of-sln-file-its-not-xml

Comment: Ignoring the name of the language, the syntax and semantics seem pretty straightforward: <typeName>NEWLINE <property>=<value>NEWLINE End<typeName>